# SQL join two tables to split email from second table

Tags: sql, join, split

I have the two following tables. Where the username from table A is the first part of the email address in table B.

How do I join the two tables together by using split? Is there another way to do this?

This is my current query:

```
    SELECT 
    A.Full_name,
    A.Username,
    B.Email,
    FROM
    A
    LEFT JOIN B
    ON A.Username = B.Email
```

I would like to use split(B.Email, '@') - however I don't think this syntax is correct.

```
Table A
--------------------------------
Full_name  | Username          |
--------------------------------
John Doe   | johndoe           |
--------------------------------
Jane Smith | janesmith         |
--------------------------------



Table B
----------------------------------
Full_name  | Email               |
----------------------------------
John Doe   | johndoe@yahoo.com   |
----------------------------------
Jane Smith | janesmith@yahoo.com |
----------------------------------
```

Comment: What RDBMS do you use?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `like` operator like this:

```
SELECT 
A.Full_name,
A.Username,
B.Email,
FROM
A
LEFT JOIN B
ON B.Email like A.Username+'@%'
```

In this case, the username will have to match exactly with text only upto the `@` character.

For SQL Server:

```
SELECT 
A.Full_name,
A.Username,
B.Email,
FROM
A
LEFT JOIN B
ON Charindex(A.Username+'@',B.Email) = 1
```

`Charindex(A.Username+'@',B.Email) = 1` because it must match from the starting of the email, not anywhere (as the other answer suggest).

Similarly, for Oracle:

```
SELECT 
A.Full_name,
A.Username,
B.Email,
FROM
A
LEFT JOIN B
ON INSTR(B.Email, A.Username||'@') = 1
```

Comment: Will it better to remove the space from `A.Username` or just irrelevant?

Comment: Sorry for my overlook ^^"

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, mssql doesn't support a split() function. You can use a combination of left() and charindex() to accomplish your objective.

```
SELECT 
A.Full_name,
A.Username,
B.Email
FROM
A
LEFT JOIN B
ON A.Username = left(B.Email, charindex(',', B.Email)-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `LIKE` operator instead of `=`

```
 SELECT 
    A.Full_name,
    A.Username,
    B.Email,
    FROM
    A
    LEFT JOIN B
    ON B.Email like A.Username+'@%'
```

Comment: The first "%" symbol in the LIKE predicate may not be necessary and it also it may prevent the index range scan.

Comment: @TechEnthusiast - Yeah not needed

Comment: Not needed? It was wrong altogether. Your second solution is still incorrect.

Comment: @GurV In what way ?

Comment: @GurV - I said leading `%` is not needed. I have no idea on what you are talking about. There is no `%` used in `charindex` say why it is wrong ?

Comment: `select charindex('jondoe@','sjondoe@gmail.com')` Your solution will join these two, when it shouldn't

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you join on `Full_name`?

```
SELECT A.Full_name, A.Username, B.Email
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
ON A.Full_name = B.Full_name
```

Comment: Because full name may not match